# How to customize sign out page in asp net core 3.1 when Azure Active Directory used in a Blazor application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Now that AzureAD/Account is baked into ASP.NET Core 3.1, how does one go about customizing the page a user ends up on after they sign out from a Blazor application using Azure AD authentication?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new Blazor on Server app w/ Azure authentication
2. Click on "Log out" (e.g. https://localhost:44320/AzureAD/Account/SignOut) link
3. User ends up on "SignedOut" page (e.g. https://localhost:44320/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut)

I've tried scaffolding the Identity Login and Logout pages, but that did not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I was close in scaffolding the Identity.
[image]

See that I checked Account\Login
and Account\Logout

I then removed Account\Login from Areas\AzureAD\Pages\Account
and renamed Logout.cshtml to SignedOut.cshtml

[image]

Also I removed the Areas\Identity\Data folder as I didn't need it.

Another issue I had was ConfigureServices was adding ControllersWithViews() which isn't needed.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        //services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        //{
        //    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        //        .Build();
        //    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        //});

        //services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    }
```